# Ruby on rails - bootstrap material design - Add checkboxes to simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I installed the [Bootstrap Material Design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design) in my Ruby on Rails application and every animation is functioning properly, but i can´t see the checkboxes. My code for the checkboxes is:

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='control-label col-sm-2'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-8'>
    <%= f.input :active, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone Help me please?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got who it's doing:

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='control-label col-sm-2'>
</div>
  <div class="checkbox col-sm-8">
      <label> <%= f.check_box :active, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true %> Active</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to add "checkbox" to the div class of the label and then you will see the checkbox animations for the bootstrap material design

Answer (score 0):

use **f.check_box** instead of **f.input** this:

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='control-label col-sm-2'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-8'>
<%= f.check_box :active, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. If i use check_box instead of input the label doesn't show. It only appears the checkbox and it isn't the material design one but the regular checkbox (without the animation).

Comment: use it like 
`<div class='form-group'>
      <div class='control-label col-sm-2'>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-8'>
        <label>
        <%= f.check_box :active, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true %> checkbox-lebel
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Thanks, now it's working, but it still uses the checkboxes without the animations, my goal is to use [this animations](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#checkbox)

Comment: **this is any example code for this animations**

`<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Notifications
    </label>
  </div>
  <p class="help-block">Notify me about updates to apps or games that I've downloaded</p>
</div>`

Comment: if u think my answers are helpful for you then give me plus point or accept my answer. thanks